# update child node xml php from another child

Tags: php, xml

please help.
I have XML file which is not filled correctly (some values are missed)

*Bad example of XML*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csv_data>
    <row>
        <brand>Maxxis</brand>
        <code>1126668/02</code>
        <articul_brand></articul_brand>
        <tiporazmer></tiporazmer>
        <name>(26/9.00 R12) 6PR TL</name>
        <model>M-966 Mudzilla</model>
        <sklad_msk></sklad_msk>
        <sklad_nahabino></sklad_nahabino>
        <sklad_chelny>8</sklad_chelny>
        <price_big_opt>6,786р.</price_big_opt>
        <price_small_opt>7,100р.</price_small_opt>
        <price_retail>8,170р.</price_retail>
    </row>
</csv_data>
```

***Good example of XML***

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <csv_data>
    <row>
        <brand>Metzeler</brand>
        <code>ЦО04257/21</code>
        <articul_brand>2491500</articul_brand>
        <tiporazmer>110/80R18</tiporazmer>
        <name>(110/80 R18) 58W TL (M) Front</name>
        <model>Roadtec Z8</model>
        <sklad_msk></sklad_msk>
        <sklad_nahabino>2</sklad_nahabino>
        <sklad_chelny></sklad_chelny>
        <price_big_opt>7,720р.</price_big_opt>
        <price_small_opt>8,106р.</price_small_opt>
        <price_retail>9,270р.</price_retail>
    </row>
</csv_data>
```

The point is that values in `<tiporazmer></tiporazmer>` are missed in bad example but they can be found in  `<name>(26/9.00 R12) 6PR TL</name>`

The question is how to update fields `<tiporazmer></tiporazmer>` using name filed? Copy that without brackets? How?

What I did, but i've got an error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in`

***Code:***

```
<?php
    $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $xml->formatOutput = true; 
    $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $xml->load('test2.xml');
    $new_tiporazmer="26/9.00 R12";

    //Get item Element
    $element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('rows')->item(0);  
    //Load child elements
    $tiporazmer = $element->getElementsByTagName('tiporazmer')->item(0);

    //Replace old elements with new
    $element->replaceChild($tiporazmer, $new_tiporazmer);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because you're calling `getElementsByTagName('rows')`, but the name of your XML node is `row`, so there shouldn't be an `s` in `rows`

Then in order to Replace old elements with new, you will need to use `nodeValue` instead of `replaceChild` unless you already have a constructed DOMDocument object ready.

---

But a better way to achieve what you want is to simply find the element by name directly, replace its text, and then save as a new file. I saved to the "/tmp" folder because permissions are usually writeable there on unix systems, but you can write anywhere your php interpreter is allowed.

```
<?php
    $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $xml->formatOutput = true; 
    $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $xml->load('test2.xml');
    $new_tiporazmer="26/9.00 R12";

    //Get item Element and Replace old elements with new
    $xml->getElementsByTagName('tiporazmer')->item(0)->nodeValue = $new_tiporazmer;

    //Save as new file
    $xml->save("/tmp/good.xml");
```

This results in good.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csv_data>
  <row>
    <brand>Maxxis</brand>
    <code>1126668/02</code>
    <articul_brand/>
    <tiporazmer>26/9.00 R12</tiporazmer>
    <name>(26/9.00 R12) 6PR TL</name>
    <model>M-966 Mudzilla</model>
    <sklad_msk/>
    <sklad_nahabino/>
    <sklad_chelny>8</sklad_chelny>
    <price_big_opt>6,786&#x440;.</price_big_opt>
    <price_small_opt>7,100&#x440;.</price_small_opt>
    <price_retail>8,170&#x440;.</price_retail>
  </row>
</csv_data>
```

Comment: thank you! it's clear now. i'll try to check empty values and fill it with new_tiporazmer getting the values from name